# gnome-tweak tool not found

Tags: gnome, package-management, kali-linux

I am using Kali GNU/Linux 1.1.0, I want to change default kali theme to some other theme, I searched different different post most of them are using gnome-tweak tool, I tried:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And then:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak tool
```

I got following message:

```
Package gnome-tweak tool is not available, but is referred to by another package
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only
available from another source.
E: Package 'gnome-tweak-tool' has no installation candidate
```

Can somebody help me on that ?

Answer (score 2):

First you need to make sure your source list is correct so it knows where to find the package, it seems this is your issue.

In a terminal issue the following commands

```
nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

In this window copy and paste the below to the bottom of the existing list

```
deb http://security.kali.org/kali-security kali/updates main contrib non-free
deb http://http.kali.org/ /wheezy main contrib non-free
```

Now save it, press `Ctrl + x` `press Y` `press enter`

Back in the terminal

```
apt-get update
apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

It should now download and install

Now issue `gnome-tweak-tool` in the terminal and it should open.

Answer (score 2):

First of all please mention the Desktop Environment of your Distribution.
By the way try this

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade 
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell gnome-shell-extensions gnome-tweak-tool
```

This generally works with gnome desktop Environment.
If still there is any error Then maintain your sources list.

Comment: OP did but indirectly.  gnome-tweak-tool only is useful for GNOME3 UI

Answer (score 1):

I see a dash missing in your post. It is `gnome-tweak-tool`instead of `gnome-tweak tool`

Comment: Except for the error: `E: Package 'gnome-tweak-tool'`, so they copy/pasted one of the names incorrectly. This could maybe have been a clarifying comment...